# Chrome doesn't show alt attribute when image is not fetched

Tags: html, google-chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/KS3vb/ I tested in IE11 and Firefox and they show alt attribute but Chrome don't.

```
<img src="http://lorempixe.com/400/300/animals" alt="A cat picture">
```

Comment: Yes. This is known and **still opened** bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=773 I don't believe there is much you can do. Some people says it works with `title` attribute, but title in chrome works as title, not as alt. If this is **really** important, you can engage some javascript and replace 404 images with text.

Comment: You could probably place the image into a div and overlay it with another div with the alternative text. Something like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/KS3vb/2/).